# Java / JSP Codings in SharePoint 2007

Tags: java, jsp, sharepoint-2007, struts2, web-parts

I notice that if one need to run java in SharePoint, one will need to embed the java into a java applet and embed into the SharePoint Content Editor Web Part or the SharePoint Page Viewer Web Part.

Are there other alternatives way to run java or jsp (java server page) and jsp framework (e.g. struts) in SharePoint? (Kindly note that this include user need to log in to the Microsoft SharePoint Site - probably using NTLM, in order to access the php web page and php framework)

Thanks.

Wilson

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to run jsp and any java technology natively on IIS web server. If you already have a framework available  you can either make use of web services to pull data into sharepoint or to use page viewer web part.

Comment: Thanks Madhur. I thought that Java products are cross-platform and there must be some way to run jsp on SharePoint (probably by using similar methods like the php.exe in IIS)

Comment: Java is cross-platform but you can't run Java/JSP outside of a Servlet Container, of which IIS is not. It's nothing like PHP's setup.